# Export MySQL table data to CSV using PHP Script

Tags: php, export-to-excel

I am working on export excel data to using php

but it has problem on downloaded as csv with comma separated values
but i need XLS file with table field values

I using the below code

```
    $values = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table");

while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) {
for ($j=0;$j<$i-1;$j++) {

$csv_output .= $rowr[$j]."; ";
}
   $csv_output .= "\n";
}
$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
print $csv_output;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rown=0;
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($values)){
  if($rown++==0)
     $csv_output.=implode(";",array_keys($row)."\n";
  $csv_output.=implode(";",array_values($row)."\n";
}
```